# Reopen windows when logging back in does not work

Tags: macos, restore, login

I have just performed a fresh re-install of El Capitan on my MBP 2014 and have found that this setting is not working at all. When I log out, I leave the check box ticked (so I **DO** want to open all applications and  my open terminal sessions to be restored, which also used to always work). When I log back in, nothing is restored, and my previous terminal sessions are lost. So how do I fix this? In general settings, I have un-ticked "Close windows when quitting an app", but I'm not sure if this is related to logout issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all of the information for the restoration is kept in **~/Library/Saved Application State**, so maybe looking there would lend a clue.  You should see a whole lot of folders ending in .savedState.

Comment: I've just checked that and the only file I see is for Dropbox (com.getdropbox.DropboxMetaInstaller.savedState), there is nothing else, so what cam I do? Thanks

Comment: Some apps (such as the ones downloaded from the Mac App Store) store their information in an isolated container separate from other apps, so why don't you check those just to be sure?  Those are in **~/Library/Containers/com.companyname.AppName/Data/Library/Saved Application State**.  If you don't see anything there, it could be that apps are simply not recording any information to be restored, which seems wacky but I can't think of any other reason why nothing would appear in Saved Application State.